# get element from complex hierarchy using cypress

Tags: javascript, get, find, cypress

I'm new to cypress. Lately, I'm trying to get the text variables within a website and push the elements into an array. However, I cannot get the element position correctly. I tried different ways such as `get(), find()` but still failed in getting **`CypressError: Timed out retryimg: Expected to find element:'.nav-link pr-0 d-none d-lg-block>.langSelector', but never found it`**

Here are my html:

```
...
<div class="nav-link pr-0 d-none d-lg-block">
  <div id="langSelector">
  <a data-dir="AAA" href="/AAA/example"> AAA </a>
  <a data-dir="BBB" href="/BBB/example"> BBB </a>
  <a data-dir="CCC" href="/CCC/example"> CCC </a>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Here are my failed try-out:

```
  cy.get('.nav-link pr-0 d-none d-lg-block > .langSelector').find('>a').each(($el) => {
          cy.wrap($el).invoke('text')
            .then(text => {
              exampleArray.push(text.trim())
            })
        })
```

And another fail try-out:

```
 cy.get('div > .langSelector > a').each(($el) => {
          cy.wrap($el).invoke('text')
          .then(text => {
            exampleArray.push(text.trim())
          })
      })
```

the error message are the same : **`CypressError: Timed out retryimg: Expected to find element:'.nav-link pr-0 d-none d-lg-block>.langSelector', but never found it`** Any ideas would be a great help! Thanks million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`langSelector` isn't a class so it shouldn't have a `.` in front of the selector. Its an `id` so it should be selected with `#`.

Try
`cy.get('#langSelector > a')`

Reference:

- [Best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#How-It-Works)

As a side note, best practice would be to use a separate attribute in your html to assign a testing specific id (something like data-tid, data-cy, etc.) and reference that for your test. This info is also in the linked reference above.